# Binding a UI element with a Vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to bind a UI element (a single-line textbox or 'input' element) with a Vuex store. [This fiddle has the code.](https://jsfiddle.net/sigint/gbpq2wvq/)

When the `SearchResult` component is visible, it auto-updates -- see the GIF below, where `Lisp` or `Prolog` is typed. That's not what I'd like to happen. What I'd really like to do is *decouple* the UI state (i.e. the value of the textbox) from the model's state, so that if I type `Lisp` and press *Search*, the `SearchResult` component updates itself.

Ideally I'd like to bind the textbox with a variable that's *not* in the store, but also add some code to observe changes to the store, so that any changes to the store are reflected in the UI.

I read the [forms handling documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/forms.html) for Vuex but wasn't very clear about the best way to get this done. Please could anyone help? I'm new to SPAs so I'm sure there's a better way of getting this done.

[image: Result of running the above fiddle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the approach you have used is the general approach if you want to use a store variable in `input`. Given that you want to decouple the UI variable with the model's state(Why?), you can do following:

1. Have a local variable in that vue instace
2. use that local variable with v-model
3. put a watch on state variable, if state variable changes, change local variable.
4. set state variable on button press, or some other way like `onblur` event

Here are relevant JS changes:

```
const app = new Vue({
    router,
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      localQuery: ''
    },
    computed: {
        query: {
            get () { return store.state.query },
            set (v) { store.commit('setquery', v) }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        s1: function () {
            console.log('app.s1 this.query: ' + this.query);
            this.query = this.localQuery
            router.push({ name: 'qpath', params: { query: this.query }});
        }
    },
    watch:{
       query: function (newVal) {
                    this.localQuery = newVal
       }
    }
})
```

see updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gbpq2wvq/5/).

Comment: Maybe the OP is thinking about some costly searches like remote search with server, then it's time for a *debounce*...

Comment: PanJunjie潘俊杰 is right, I was hoping to build a predictive autocomplete feature into the textbox. Your point about debouncing is very helpful, I'm reading up on that now.

Comment: Shouldn't  the setter dispatch an action instead of commiting ?